# ApostropheCMS: Redirect to previous page after login

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm working on an Intranet and all my Sites are only accessable when the user is logged in. We want to send Newsletters for special News-Releases.

I have the following scenario:

- Enter the Site through a Newsletter.
- Link is set to something like `www.exampleproject.com/news`
- Since not LoggedIn -> Site redirects to `/login`
- Clientside: `document.referrer` has my previous Pagelink stored
- After a successful login the user is redirected to `/` (Home)

So i know that i have the Information i need in my client. But i don't know how and where i should pass it.

Did someone implement something like that already or has a clue about my problem?

Comment: Are you sending the user to the login page based on something custom?

Comment: I am only sending the user to the login page, if he is not logged in, since the site is only accessable logged-in. @StuartRomanek
I put a hidden input into my login-form, and filled it with a `document.referrer` in a `<script>`. after that i have my old link in the `index.js`.
I then use the var to overwrite `req.redirect` with my new value.
its a solution but i think thats not the way i should be doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is available via the [apostrophe-second-chance-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apostrophe-second-chance-login) module. When this npm module is installed and configured (per the README), requests for pages that would otherwise 404 due to permissions result in a login prompt followed by a redirect to the page.